# In Google Drive spreadsheet, how do I put tabs at the top of the screen?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to make a public Google Doc with tabs similar to https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AifXEOqTcGcLdFVvWk1GRjVJTHJUaTVLcGViR1RRTFE, but I haven't been able to find instructions or other examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tabs appear at the top of the document when using the "Published" view.
You can see this by going to File, Publish to the Web..., and click Start publishing.

If you copy and open the resulting link, you will see a read only view with the tabs at the top and none of the spreadsheet UI.